# received Error: failed to invert matrix when add in deckGL in Reactjs hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, deck.gl, react-map-gl

im new in reactjs and deckGL and im having a little problem with the code below. I am trying to add DeckGL with FlyToInterpolator to center the marker. I'm receiving this error after I clicked the button, but when i'm using the react-map-gl + FlyToInterpolator it works.

update: the issue is, I having a problem when using FlyToInterpolar API in deckGL, but I have no issue using FlyToInterpolar in react-map-gl.

Please help! thank you very much 
p/s: sorry english is not my main language.

error:

```
Error: failed to invert matrix
▶ 3 stack frames were collapsed.
Mapbox._updateMapViewport
src/mapbox/mapbox.js:434
  431 |   newViewState.altitude !== oldViewState.altitude;
  432 | 
  433 | if (viewportChanged) {
> 434 |   this._map.jumpTo(this._viewStateToMapboxProps(newViewState));
      | ^  435 | 
  436 |   // TODO - jumpTo doesn't handle altitude
  437 |   if (newViewState.altitude !== oldViewState.altitude) {
View compiled
Mapbox._update
src/mapbox/mapbox.js:400
  397 | newProps = Object.assign({}, this.props, newProps);
  398 | checkPropTypes(newProps, 'Mapbox');
  399 | 
> 400 | const viewportChanged = this._updateMapViewport(oldProps, newProps);
      | ^  401 | const sizeChanged = this._updateMapSize(oldProps, newProps);
  402 | 
  403 | if (!newProps.asyncRender && (viewportChanged || sizeChanged)) {
View compiled
Mapbox.setProps
src/mapbox/mapbox.js:213
  210 | }
  211 | 
  212 | setProps(props: Props) {
> 213 |   this._update(this.props, props);
      | ^  214 |   return this;
  215 | }
  216 | 
View compiled
StaticMap._updateMapProps
src/components/static-map.js:213
  210 | if (!this._mapbox) {
  211 |   return;
  212 | }
> 213 | this._mapbox.setProps(
      | ^  214 |   Object.assign({}, props, {
  215 |     width: this._width,
  216 |     height: this._height
View compiled
StaticMap.componentDidUpdate
src/components/static-map.js:152
  149 | componentDidUpdate(prevProps: StaticMapProps) {
  150 |   if (this._mapbox) {
  151 |     this._updateMapStyle(prevProps, this.props);
> 152 |     this._updateMapProps(this.props);
      | ^  153 |   }
  154 | }
  155 | 
View compiled
▶ 19 stack frames were collapsed.
DeckGL._customRender
src/deckgl.js:148
  145 |   // Viewports have changed, update children props first.
  146 |   // This will delay the Deck canvas redraw till after React update (in componentDidUpdate)
  147 |   // so that the canvas does not get rendered before the child components update.
> 148 |   this.forceUpdate();
      | ^  149 | } else {
  150 |   this._redrawDeck();
  151 | }
View compiled
Deck.redraw
src/lib/deck.js:351
  348 | 
  349 | this.stats.get('Redraw Count').incrementCount();
  350 | if (this.props._customRender) {
> 351 |   this.props._customRender(redrawReason);
      | ^  352 | } else {
  353 |   this._drawLayers(redrawReason);
  354 | }
View compiled
Deck._onRenderFrame
src/lib/deck.js:707
  704 | this._pickAndCallback();
  705 | 
  706 | // Redraw if necessary
> 707 | this.redraw(false);
      | ^  708 | 
  709 | // Update viewport transition if needed
  710 | // Note: this can trigger `onViewStateChange`, and affect layers
View compiled
AnimationLoop.onRender
src/lib/animation-loop.js:252
  249 | }
  250 | 
  251 | onRender(...args) {
> 252 |   return this.props.onRender(...args);
      | ^  253 | }
  254 | 
  255 | onFinalize(...args) {
View compiled
AnimationLoop._renderFrame
src/lib/animation-loop.js:340
  337 |   }
  338 | 
  339 |   // call callback
> 340 |   this.onRender(...args);
      | ^  341 |   // end callback
  342 | }
  343 | 
View compiled
AnimationLoop.redraw
src/lib/animation-loop.js:178
  175 | this._setupFrame();
  176 | this._updateCallbackData();
  177 | 
> 178 | this._renderFrame(this.animationProps);
      | ^  179 | 
  180 | // clear needsRedraw flag
  181 | this._clearNeedsRedraw();
View compiled
renderFrame
src/lib/animation-loop.js:279
  276 |   if (!this._running) {
  277 |     return;
  278 |   }
> 279 |   this.redraw();
      | ^  280 |   this._animationFrameId = this._requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);
  281 | };
  282 | 
View compiled
```

Code:

```
const MAPBOX_TOKEN = // Set your mapbox token here
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    box: {
    borderStyle: "solid",
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    zIndex: -1
    },
  })

const MapHooks = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const [fleetDetail, setFleetDetail] = useState(null)
    const [mapRef, setMapRef] = useState(null);
    const classes = useStyles()
    const sigfox = ApiSigfox()

    const [mapping, setMapping] = useState({
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        longitude: -73.989308,
        latitude: 40.741895,
        zoom: 12
      });

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({ 
        _goToNYC(e) {        
            Object.values(sigfox).map((docs) => {
                return (e === docs.device) ? (
                    updateMap(docs)
                ) : null
            })        
        }
    }));    

    //update Map
    function updateMap(test){
        console.log(test.device + '-' + 'updateMap')
        const viewport = {
            ...mapping,
            longitude: test.lon,
            latitude: test.lat,
            zoom: 14,
            transitionDuration: 2000,
            transitionInterpolator: new FlyToInterpolator(),
            transitionEasing: d3.easeCubic
        };
        setMapping(viewport)
        console.log(mapping)
    }

    return (
        <div className={classes.box} style={{borderStyle: "solid"}}>
            <DeckGL viewState={mapping} controller={true} onViewStateChange={setMapping}>
                <StaticMap             
                mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11"
                mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
                >                              
                    {Object.values(sigfox).map((docs) => {
                        return (docs.status !== 255 && (docs.lat >= -90 && docs.lat <= 90) ) ? 
                        <Marker 
                            key={docs.id} 
                            latitude={docs.lat} 
                            longitude={docs.lon} 
                            offsetTop={-35}
                            offsetLeft={-8}
                        >                           
                            <div>  
                                <button onClick={e => {e.preventDefault(); setFleetDetail(docs)}}>{docs.device}</button> 
                            </div>                       
                        </Marker>
                    : null
                    })} 
                    {/* display the pop up detail when click the icon */}
                    {fleetDetail ? (
                    <Popup
                    latitude={fleetDetail.lat}
                    longitude={fleetDetail.lon}
                    onClose={()=>{
                        setFleetDetail(null)
                    }}          
                    >
                    <div> 
                        <p>Device:{fleetDetail.device}</p>          
                        <p>Latitude:{fleetDetail.lat}</p>
                        <p>Longitude:{fleetDetail.lon}</p>
                        <p>status:{fleetDetail.status}</p>
                    </div>
                    </Popup>
                    ): null}               
                </StaticMap>
            </DeckGL>           
        </div>
    );
})
```

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Can you write the error you receive in as a code section instead of linking to it as an external image. Also the text " I'm receiving this error after I clicked the button, but when i'm using the react-map-gl + FlyToInterpolator it works." is sort of unclear. Does this mean it works when you load the map, but when you click the button you get the error?

Comment: @user254694  hi thank you for the  reply, so sorry I updated the the error. There is no issue when I load the map, Im having issue when using FlytoInterpolar API in DeckGL, while i have no issue using FlytoInterpolar API in React-map-gl.